# how to find this jacobian?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, jacobian

[image]

I'm confused. We are only given information about the partial derivatives with respect to $t$ and not $s$. How are we then able to deduce the jacobian at $0$? any hint?

Comment: You are also given information about the behaviour of the functions at $t=0$, which is enough to compute the partial derivatives wrt s at $t=0$.

Comment: @Reveillark I can't see how?

Comment: $\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}(0,s)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x(0,s+h)-x(0,s)}{h}$

Comment: Why is dx/dt 3 dimensional when it should be one dimensional? @Reveillark

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Both partial derivatives of $x$ are real-valued functions of two variables.